# How to refer to a class in a new window using Jquery

Tags: jquery, class, selector

Let's say I open a new window and write the contents of an existing window div element into it...

```
var mywindow = window.open('', 'print_window', 'toolbar=no, resizable=no, width=1000);

var current_contents = $('#detail_div').html();

mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print Window</title></head><body>');
mywindow.document.write('<div id="print_container">'+current_contents+'</div>');
mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
```

Now suppose that there are elements with the class "print_hide" in from the existing window we want to hide in the new window.

I've tried

```
$('.print_hide').hide();
```

But that only references the original (parent?) window.

None of this worked either...

```
$(mywindow.document.body '> .print_hide').hide();
$mywindow.document('.print_hide').hide();
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Change the below line with your code, this should do the trick :

```
 mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print Window</title><style>.print_hide{display:none}</style></head><body>');
```

Comment: Thanks Nalin!  It's a smart workaround.  Wondering still if it is nonetheless possible to access the new window classes for real time interaction.

Comment: @Hank well it's possible, you can do this, by appending the style of class in the header of the window!! as I have done. I don't think if it's possible to call from parent to child for a style :) Happy codding. Hope it helps !!

Comment: OK, than you Nalin.  I voted for your post but my noob status means it does not count!